# Why is window.location.reload() negating the previous command?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a HTTP POST/DELETE request in javascript to delete a message in my rails app

```
 $.post(message_url, { _method: 'delete' }, null, "script");
```

If I refresh my browser on the page after I execute this line, I see that that the message has been in fact delete and no longer appears.

Now I want the page to automatically refresh after this command so the user sees its gone. I have the following lines:

```
    $.post(message_url, { _method: 'delete' }, null, "script");
    window.location.reload();
```

Now the page does indeed refresh but the message no longer gets delete. And I don't see any errors in the console.

So basically, without this reload(); command the message deletes just fine, but if I add this reload() line it stops working. Why is this happening?

More to the point, how could I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" is that `$.post` is asynchronous. That means that when you call it, it fires off an AJAX request to the server (to delete that message). Since it's asynchronous, the Javascript continues running (it doesn't wait for the AJAX request to complete in order to continue to run the rest of your code (`window.location.reload()`). Since it doesn't wait, `window.location.reload()` runs immediately after the request is fired off and is probably aborted (because the browser is being redirected to a new page and that is the default behavior).

The solution is to execute the `reload()` on complete of the `$.post` call:

```
$.post(message_url, { _method: 'delete' }, function () {
    window.location.reload();
}, "script");
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @pejmanjohn No problem. Are you sure you want to refresh the page though? It seems silly if you're using AJAX immediately before the refresh - you might as well allow for a normal form submit. The thing that would make sense to do after the delete is retrieve the new list of "messages" and display them...or simply remove the container that the deleted "message" was in (effectively removing it from the page and disallowing further interaction.

Comment: Appreciate the further input. I actually want the refresh (for UX reasons - this is a fairly severe action & it actually makes it clearer that something happened). Funny enough I've always done these things via AJAX before hence why I'm not sure how to write a normal form submit. Hence why I'm asking such an odd question.

Comment: @pejmanjohn I'm all for UX reasons, but I don't think a page refresh is really what you should do (I guess it's just my opinion though). You have many options/combinations, but not limited to: a modal shown on success, a "loading" spinner/overlay, some notification on the page (whether that be a flash of the content, a new color used, etc.), or a message just saying what happened and when. `fadeOut`, `fadeIn` and the plethora of other jQuery animations are very useful :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to wait until the ajax request finishes before you refresh the page, since ajax is asynchronous its still being executed when the `window.location.reload();` which cancels the ajax request. You can use the success parameter in the [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

```
$.post(message_url, { _method: 'delete' }, function(){window.location.reload();}, "script");
```

That being said, this kind of defeats the purpose of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when the page unloads, all AJAX requests are cancelled.

Since the AJAX call is asynchronous,the call to reload happens immediately and the request is cancelled.

You have to wait until the AJAX call is finished by adding it to success callback